# How to round a number upto n decimal places in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, rounding

[image]I have column in table which I want to round upto some decimal places.
Which is stored in some other table.

Actually my data is stored as 8 decimal places, but based on user preference, I need to show upto that decimal place.

Column datatype is numeric(19,8)

I have procedure which is returning all rows. So At that time only I want to round my column up to specified decimal decimal

Want to do something like

```
declare @i int = 2
Begin
select cast (12533333.193 as numeric(38,@i))
end
```

how to achieve this?
Please suggest

Comment: give us some sample data to try it on and maybe some column defenitions

Comment: The rounding will be done when you store it in the other table. No need to do anything explicit before INSERT/UPDATE.

Comment: @JeremyC. updated the original question

Comment: @jarlh See my scenario. updated in post

Comment: in what type of field is your data saved in the database?

Comment: @JeremyC. It is numeric(19,8)

Comment: Then you can just use Round() without the casting

Comment: @JeremyC. 
Round(125.2369,2) will give me 125.2300

Comment: it gives me 125.23 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/06b5e/1, are you loading the result into a view where the precision is set to 4?

Comment: @JeremyC. Thanks for your time. See screenshot

Comment: Well your round is happening properly, it's just your display that is wrong, your display is set to 4 decimal places that's why it's showing x.2400 instead of the x.2369

Comment: @vishal where are you viewing your data? sql server workbench or something?

Comment: @JeremyC.I am viewing on sql server management studio 2012 express edition

Answer (score 1):

**This is the MOST easy of all**

Before starting I want to tell that this works only for float type (Yes! you need to convert your decimals / numerics to float!). Syntax wise it is **Most Readable** as well!

`select round(cast(65.456 as float),2)` *(This will round off to 2 decimal places)*

`select round(cast(65.456 as float),1)` *(This will round off to 1 decimal places)*

`select round(cast(65.456 as float),0)` *(This will round off to 0 decimal places)*

*See the snapshot below*

[image: Snapshot]

Comment: float is not a precise type and you can have nasty surprises when you are using it. Consider to use decimal instead.

Comment: this doesn't works with decimal as value type. Only when we typecast as **float** then only it takes care of expected decimal points.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the ROUND function for sql-server

```
DECLARE @i int = 2
BEGIN
SELECT ROUND(val,@i)
FROM mytable
END
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a85a4/1)

Comment: Round(125.2369,2) will give me 125.2300- its not what I want

Answer (score 0):

you can cast to number with 2 decimal after round up in query,

or when you display at report or system

```
DECLARE @i int = 2
BEGIN
SELECT 
cast(
    ROUND(val,@i)
    as decimal(10,2)
)
FROM mytable
END
```

Comment: I dont know how many decimal places I need to cast. you cant do as decimal(10,@i)